# VAMT Indicates two revision levels are incompatible

Tags: kms

I'm trying to add/run Office 2016 to the KMS server. The KMS server is currently Server 2016 std.
Running the package for this installs and then brings up VAT.
I try entering the KMS key and try activating it but I get the following error.

`indicates two revision levels are incompatible`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and worked around it by doing the following:

1. Ran Volume Activation Tool, and installed Windows Server 2016 KMS-key.
2. Then ran `slmgr.vbs /ato` - this activated my Windows Server 2016 KMS.
3. Ran the Office KMS setup (kms_host.vbs), and insterted the KMS for Office2016.
4. Then `slmgr.vbs /ato 98ebfe73-2084-4c97-932c-c0cd1643bea7`
5. Repeat for Office 2013, but `slmgr.vbs /ato 2E28138A-847F-42BC-9752-61B03FFF33CD`